# Create CloudFormation template in YAML to create following resources and output

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, ubuntu-18.04

Create web server instance in an AZ, Create Target Group, Create Load balancer using CloudFormation template to manage AWS resource.

Here is the scenario as follows:

Create CloudFormation template to create following resources and output

- Required parameters ○ Web Server Security Group
- Web Server: AMI - Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, t2.micro, Install apache web server using user data
- Target group referring created web server
- Application Load balancer
- Listener referring load balancer and target group
- Output load balancer URL

Using YAML:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: AWS cloudformation template to create ec2 instance with http apache web server, target group, and load balancer.
This template creates one or more Amazon EC2 instances and an application Load Balancer.
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 Keypair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: project04
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  InstanceType:
    Description: WebServer EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
  AmiId:
    Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS AMI Id
    Type: String
    Default: ami-0ac019f4fcb7cb7e6
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: 9
    MaxLength: 18
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: (\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

Resources:
 WebServerInstance:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
   Properties:
     InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
     SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'WebServerSecurityGroup']
     KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
     ImageId: !Ref "AmiId"
     UserData:
         Fn::Base64:
             Fn::Join: 
               -"
               --|
                     #!/bin/bash
                    -'# Launching Instance'
                    -|
                     sudo apt-get update -y
                     sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
    GroupDescription: Enable SSH traffic and HTTP access
       SecurityGroupIngress:
         IpProtocol: tcp
         FromPort: 22
         ToPort: 22
         CidrIp: !Ref 'SSHLocation'
         IpProtocol: tcp
         FromPort: 80
         ToPort: 80
         CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: The URL of the sample website
    Value: !Join ['', ['http://', !GetAtt [WebServerInstance, PublicDNSName]]]
```

Need help and provide YAML code for:

- Target group referring created web server
- Application Load balancer
- Listener referring load balancer and target group

Kindly advise to provide YAML code for CloudFormation template unable to find for above.

Comment: Is this an actual business requirement or is this an assignment you are doing for some course?

Comment: [ElasticLoadBalancingV2 Resource Type Reference - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ElasticLoadBalancingV2.html)

Comment: Yes this is a demo for the business requirement. Need help on the following code  
- Target group referring created web server
- Application Load balancer
- Listener referring load balancer and target group

Where unable to use for above YAML code template as mentioned 

Please advise

Comment: Why are you unable to use the above documentation?

Comment: Thanks for the link sharing. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ElasticLoadBalancingV2.html Link confuses .

Comment: Receiving an  6/24/2019, 12:47:19 PM - Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 40, column 17)

Comment: Kindly please help and share the correct cloudformation code of YAML for above requirement

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not a site for requesting other people to write code for you. If you have a question, you are welcome to post relevant information including your code the error you are receiving and what you have tried to fix the error. People might then be able to assist you. For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The loadbalancer fails in the folowing code

Comment: The loadbalancer fails in the folowing code and unable to create stack:

The following resource(s) failed to create: [EC2Instance, ApplicationLoadBalancer]. . Rollback requested by user.

Resource creation cancelled

Value of property Subnets must be of type List of String

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) to generate yaml or json snippet for aws cloudformation resources. cloudkast is an online cloudformation template generator. It is very intuitive and easy to use.